# Ansible, k8s and variables

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, openshift

I'm using Ansible and the `k8s` module for deploying applications to an OpenShift cluster. In general this is working really well.

However, when I try to set the port value, in a deployment config, using a value from a variable, things are not so happy.

I have the following ansible task as an example:

```
- name: Create app service
      k8s:
        name: "{{ name | lower }}"
        state: present
        definition:
          apiVersion: v1
          kind: Service
          metadata:
            annotations:
            labels:
              app: "{{ name | lower }}"
            name: "{{ name | lower }}"
            namespace: "{{ name | lower }}"
          spec:
            ports:
              - name: "{{ port }}-tcp"
                port: "{{ port  }}"
                protocol: TCP
                targetPort: "{{ port | int }}" <--- the problem!
            selector:
              deploymentconfig: "{{ name | lower }}"
            sessionAffinity: None
            type: ClusterIP
          status:
            loadBalancer: {}
```

The variable is set in a yaml file, which is read into the playbook, and the variable is set like `port: "5000"`.

If I change this to `port: 5000` then it solves the problem, but I use this variable in several other places and other playbooks, so I would prefer to keep the variable as is.

I have tried using the approaches to solve this:
`"{{ port | int }}"`

An example of the error I get is:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "error": 422, "msg": "Failed to patch object: {\"kind\":\"Status\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"metadata\":{},\"status\":\"Failure\",\"message\":\"Service \\\"myapp\\\" is invalid: spec.ports[0].targetPort: Invalid value: \\\"7001\\\": must contain at least one letter or number (a-z, 0-9)\",\"reason\":\"Invalid\",\"details\":{\"name\":\"usdt-wallet\",\"kind\":\"Service\",\"causes\":[{\"reason\":\"FieldValueInvalid\",\"message\":\"Invalid value: \\\"5000\\\": must contain at least one letter or number (a-z, 0-9)\",\"field\":\"spec.ports[0].targetPort\"}]},\"code\":422}\n", "reason": "Unprocessable Entity", "status": 422}
```

Comment: Why not just specify it as an int in your yaml file (`port: 5000`), and then convert it to a string when and if necessary? It's not clear in what situations specifying it as an int is going to fail; are you sure that it won't Just Work?  There's always `{{ port|str }}`.

Comment: That errors with `{"msg": "template error while templating string: no filter named 'str'. String: {{ port|str }}"}`. I think the 'k8s' module is not working with filters. Some work, such as `lower` but `str` isnt

Answer (score 1):

According to the posted error message, your problem isn't `|int` or `|string` -- although I agree the error message is misleading:

> "message": "Service \"usdt-wallet\" is invalid: spec.ports[0].targetPort: Invalid value: \"70001\": must contain at least one letter or number (a-z, 0-9)",

but it is caused by trying to use 70001 as a target port but TCP ports must be in the range 1 to 65535 inclusive, as stated by [the fine manual](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#serviceport-v1-core)

Comment: Good spotting. I was initially trying to use port 7000 but changed it to 70001 to check that my changes were being picked up. However, the error is about misreading the value from the variable.

Comment: uuh, it's `|string` not `|str` 