# How to use k8s Ansible module without quotes?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I am trying to use the module [community.kubernetes.k8s – Manage Kubernetes (K8s) objects](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/kubernetes/k8s_module.html) with variables from the role (e.g. role/sampleRole/vars file).

I am failing when it comes to the integer point e.g.:

```yaml
- name: sample                                                                                                                                                         
  community.kubernetes.k8s:                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  state: present                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  definition:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    apiVersion: apps/v1                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    kind: Deployment                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    metadata:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      name: "{{ name }}"
      namespace: "{{ namespace }}"                                                                                                                                                                                             
      labels:
        app: "{{ app }}"                                                                                                                                                                                              
    spec:
      replicas: 2
        selector:
          matchLabels:
            app: "{{ app }}"                                                                                                                                                                                    
        template:
          metadata:
            labels:
              app: "{{ app }}"                                                                                                                                                                                
          spec:
            containers:
            - name: "{{ name }}"                                                                                                                                                                                  
              image: "{{ image }}"                                                                                                                                                                                
              ports:
              - containerPort: {{ containerPort }}
```

When I deploy with this format obviously it will fail at it can not parse the "reference" to the var.

Sample of error:

```sh
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found unacceptable key (unhashable type: 'AnsibleMapping')

The error appears to be in 'deploy.yml': line <some line>, column <some column>, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

              ports:
              - containerPort: {{ containerPort }}
                                ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

When I use quotes on the variable e.g. `- containerPort: "{{ containerPort }}"` then I get the following error (part of it):

```sh
v1.Deployment.Spec: v1.DeploymentSpec.Template: v1.PodTemplateSpec.Spec: v1.PodSpec.Containers: []v1.Container: v1.Container.Ports: []v1.ContainerPort: v1.ContainerPort.ContainerPort: readUint32: unexpected character: \\\\ufffd, error found in #10 byte of ...|nerPort\\\\\":\\\\\"80\\\\\"}]}],\\\\\"d|..., bigger context ...|\\\\\",\\\\\"name\\\\\":\\\\\"samplegreen\\\\\",\\\\\"ports\\\\\":[{\\\\\"containerPort\\\\\":\\\\\"80\\\\\"}]}],\\\\\"dnsPolicy\\\\\":\\\\\"ClusterFirst\\\\\",\\\\\"restartPolicy\\\\\"|...\",\"field\":\"patch\"}]},\"code\":422}\\n'", "reason": "Unprocessable Entity", "status": 422}
```

I tried to cast the string to int by using `- containerPort: "{{ containerPort | int }}"` but it did not worked. The problem seems to be coming from the quotes, independently how I define the var in my var file e.g. `containerPort: 80` or `containerPort: "80"`.

I found a similar question on the forum [Ansible, k8s and variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55821144/ansible-k8s-and-variables) but the user seems not to have the same problems that I am having.

I am running with the latest version of the module:

```sh
$ python3 -m pip show openshift
Name: openshift
Version: 0.11.2
Summary: OpenShift python client
Home-page: https://github.com/openshift/openshift-restclient-python
Author: OpenShift
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: Apache License Version 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages
Requires: ruamel.yaml, python-string-utils, jinja2, six, kubernetes
```

Is there any workaround this problem or is it a bug?

**Update (08-01-2020):** The problem is fixed on version 0.17.0.

```sh
$ python3 -m pip show k8s
Name: k8s
Version: 0.17.0
Summary: Python client library for the Kubernetes API
Home-page: https://github.com/fiaas/k8s
Author: FiaaS developers
Author-email: fiaas@googlegroups.com
License: Apache License
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages
Requires: requests, pyrfc3339, six, cachetools
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are setting `containerPort`?

Comment: @larsks it does not matter whether I define it like `containerPort: "80"` or `containerPort: 80` still the error is the same.

Comment: [You must quote the Jinja template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#when-to-quote-variables-a-yaml-gotcha) lest you get this exact YAML error.  Does `containerPort: "{{ containerPort }}"` work, even if it looks like the wrong type?  Or `"{{ containerPort | int }}"`?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have tried both including the casting and without. The error is coming from the quotes. I need to find a way to not to use the quotes as larsks proposed. His example is working just fine but it is kind of a workaround. I assume this is a bug. I will raise it on github.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the following as a workaround; in this example, we're creating a text template, and then using the `from_yaml` filter to transform this into our desired data structure:

```
- name: sample                                                                                                                                                         
  community.kubernetes.k8s:                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    state: present                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    definition:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      apiVersion: apps/v1                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      kind: Deployment                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
      metadata:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        name: "{{ name }}"
        namespace: "{{ namespace }}"                                                                                                                                                                                             
        labels:
          app: "{{ app }}"                                                                                                                                                                                              
      spec: "{{ spec|from_yaml }}"
  vars:
    spec: |
      replicas: 2
        selector:
          matchLabels:
            app: "{{ app }}"                                                                                                                                                                                    
        template:
          metadata:
            labels:
              app: "{{ app }}"                                                                                                                                                                                
          spec:
            containers:
            - name: "{{ name }}"                                                                                                                                                                                  
              image: "{{ image }}"                                                                                                                                                                                
              ports:
              - containerPort: {{ containerPort }}
```

Comment: Very interesting I did not think about that. Thanks I will keep the question open for the moment before I accept this answer. I am curious if someone else has reported the bug (as it seems) earlier and knows a specific version that works.

Comment: You are not alone, there are more folks with this Ansible's Jinja "int vs string" issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63961938/ansible-variable-conversion-to-int-is-ignored

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by larsks works perfectly. Although I got another problem on my case where I use templates with a bit more complex cases (e.g. loops etc) where I found my self having the same problem.

The only solution that I had before was to use [ansible.builtin.template – Template a file out to a remote server](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) and simply ssh the some_file.yml.j2 to one of my Master nodes and deploy through [ansible.builtin.shell – Execute shell commands on targets](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html) (e.g. `kubectl apply -f some_file.yml`).

Thanks to [community.kubernetes.k8s – Manage Kubernetes (K8s) objects](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/kubernetes/k8s_module.html) I am able to do all this work with a single task e.g. (example taken from documentation):

```yaml
- name: Read definition template file from the Ansible controller file system
  community.kubernetes.k8s:
    state: present
    template: '/testing/deployment.j2'
```

The only requirement that the user needs to have in advance is to have the kubeconfig file placed in the default location (~/.kube/config) or use the [kubeconfig](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/kubernetes/k8s_module.html#parameter-kubeconfig) flag to point to the location of the file.

As a last step I use it [delegate_to](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html) to localhost command e.g.

```yaml
- name: Read definition template file from the Ansible controller file system
  community.kubernetes.k8s:
    state: present
    template: '/testing/deployment.j2'
  delegate_to: localhost
```

The way that this task works is that the user ssh to himself and run `kubectl apply -f some_file.yml.j2` towards the LB or Master node API and the API applies the request (if the user has the permissions).